# Windows 10 - How to check if a particular key exists on the keyboard (using Win32 API)

Tags: winapi, keyboard, autoit

I want to check to see if the attached keyboard has a particular key. In this instance, I want to know if the Windows key is present, since many keyboards do not have it.

I'm coding in AutoIt, but that shouldn't matter since I can use any WinAPI function.

Thanks

Comment: Try [`MapVirtualKey(VK_LWIN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) (or `VK_RWIN`). It translates a virtual key code into a hardware scan code, or returns 0 if there is no translation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm sorry to say that even if there is no attached keyboard, *`MapVirtualKey`* also works. We may use the information contained in [`Win32_Keyboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-keyboard) to check keyboard kind.

Comment: Thanks, @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, but I'm afraid your reply is over my head. Could you simplify it or point me to a clear example, if not in AutoIt then perhaps in pseudo-code or Basic, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*`Win32_Keyboard`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-keyboard#properties) Properties to get keyboard information so that you can know if the Windows key is present.
The following code is adapted from [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer).

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    //
    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    TCHAR ClassPath[] = L"Win32_Keyboard";//Win32_OperatingSystem=@ is instance
    hres = pSvc->GetObjectW(ClassPath, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        VariantInit(&vtProp);
        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " Win32_Keyboard Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        VariantInit(&vtProp);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Layout", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " Win32_Keyboard Layout : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        VariantInit(&vtProp);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"NumberOfFunctionKeys", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " Win32_Keyboard NumberOfFunctionKeys : " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```

[image: Result]